# Powershell+Ubuntu. How do you call Selenium?

Tags: powershell, selenium, ubuntu

How do you call Selenium in Powershell on Ubuntu?

In Windows you would do:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\selenium\net40\WebDriver.dll")
$ie = New-Object OpenQA.Selenium.PhantomJS.PhantomJSDriver
```

But I don't know how to do this in Ubuntu.

Comment: Any reason you're trying to use Powershell on Linux rather than using the Java, Python or Ruby Selenium Libraries? Powershell on Linux is a very new technology and not widely supported unlike all the other languages I mentioned.

Comment: Please edit the question, providing details about how you start selenium from a standard shell like Bash. Then maybe others can help you deduce how to port that to PS. Start simple, then get fancier step by step.